# Jquery ajax call not working with relative and absolute urls

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is the code, I don't get any alerts whether, error or success. That ajax call returns a json map, and that map is populated in the `select` options dynamically.

```
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var selectValues;
        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/",
              data: APP_002,
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                selectValues = data;
                  alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
              },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });

            var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor');
            var $model = $('select.model');
            $vendor.change(
                          function() {
                              $model.empty().append(function() {
                                  var output = '';
                                  $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                                      output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
                                  });
                                  return output;
                              });
                          }).change();

            // bonus: how to access the download link
            $model.change(function() {
                $('a#download-link').attr('href', selectValues[$vendor.val()][$model.val()]).show();
            });
});
</script>
<div>
    <select class="mobile-vendor">
        <option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
        <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
        <option value="android">Android</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>

    <select class="model"></select>
    <a id="download-link"> Download </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Why it can't it send the request to the server, I'm using logs in the server side. No request there.

The page url : http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/download/

Ajex request Url : http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/

I used both `/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/` and `http://myhost.com/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/` as the parameter for url in the ajax method, both are not working.

Comment: What errors (if any) are you getting in the console/Firebug? Also, where is the `APP_002` variable coming from?

Comment: http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/ seems empty. My browser returns 404. Is that real URL?

Comment: There is no relevant logs for that URL, and I just hard coded that APP_002 id, it doesn't matter ne..?

Comment: can you post the content of APP_002? If it is not valid somehow, it blocks the execution of JS

Comment: @Ottomanlast : You need to pass a parameter, like, APP_002. And App_002 is a string which is append to the url in the ajax call.

Comment: @Ottomanlast : You can try like `http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/APP_008`

Comment: I think he knows that, he was asking what the data in `APP_002` is. Also, is it `APP_002` or `App_002` - javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: I think the problem is you're passing `APP_002` using the data parameter, which is equivalent in this case to the querystring. Looking at the example above, you need to actually pass it in directly in the URL so that the request is routed correctly on the server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : That will be dynamically passed in the future, basically, it's a string, I will use that string parameter in the server side in future, you can pass any string there.

Comment: In that case it's not working because the server processing code hasn't been writted to use the querystring variable you're giving it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : So, what is the purpose of the `data` in the ajax method? I thought, what ever in the `data`, will be append to the `url` and requested to the server. Isn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4912/discussion-between-rory-mccrossan-and-kugathasan-abimaran)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code on your server (link you provided) is not the same as the one you have posted in your question. Code there has error: SCRIPT1009: Expected '}' meaning that you are missing } from your javascript.

Line:

```
// bonus: how to access the download link
```

comments out the rest of javascript as you have not switched it to a new row. This commented js includes some code and closing braces. You should add newline after this comment.
This is why you have javascript error and your browser never calls server.

And your parameter should be 'APP_002', not just APP_002

When you fix this, you will probably be able to make request, but if not, we can check for any other errors when you do this.

Comment: Thank, Ive removed the commented line.

Comment: Is it working now? Can you format your script nicely on the server so it can be debugged? You should probably use some text editor which suports converting line feeds from windows to unix format before uploading to server.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're passing `APP_002` using the data parameter, which is equivalent in this case to the querystring. Looking your comments on the OP, you need to actually pass it in directly in the URL so that the request is routed correctly on the server, like this:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/APP_002",
          async: false,
          // rest of your code...
   });
```

Example:

http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/?APP_002 -> page not found

http://59.163.254.24:4287/wap/retrieve/hanset/data/APP_002 -> JSON response

Comment: No improvements, how can I make sure, my ajax call is working..?

Comment: I check with Developer tool in chrome, and I got, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. How to find on which line?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is not a problem with the code you provided.
Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fHtcc/1/

However, there must be an issue with APP_002 (if it is not something defined) or Jquery is not included to page.

Comment: I have tried replacing that with a string 'APP_002' but you cannot call his server from jsfiddle because of same origin policy. However, his code on his site is not the same he posted here (it is all in one long line there).

Comment: description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var$1 cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
 hms.appstore.wap.Core.service(Unknown Source)